# Can "whiff" be used to refer to physical objects instead of conceptual ideas?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know you can say things like:

> The only whiff of disorientation came from the hundreds of eggs
>   littered around the stage [[...]](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjACahUKEwj99LPW5aPIAhXMkZQKHZI5Cx8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsosogay.co.uk%2F2013%2Fopinion-the-shock-factor%2F&usg=AFQjCNEwPHSRm6AlkP6KPBT6QQKsSt9PNQ&sig2=9W729KBoohBX8PhPpwQdLw)
>   The only whiff of homophobia came from the Library's old-fashioned internal  printing shop. [[...]](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAEahUKEwj99LPW5aPIAhXMkZQKHZI5Cx8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkeepthelightsonfilm.com%2Farchives%2Fgay-new-york%2Fwhat-to-do-until-the-poet-comes-part-3&usg=AFQjCNEffKcPIbvIIHvxNGpFeVQpHYbSJA&sig2=x5aO-oJZ6iDNvGwL6rZ58Q)

These are usually abstract concepts (I may be mistaken). Is it common to use the same construction to refer to something physical like a class?

Example:

> The only whiff of chemistry class came from the periodic table
>   next to the window.

(There wasn't anything in the classroom that told students that that was a chemistry class, except for the periodic table next to the window.)

Comment: Yep, that's fine too, but you're  still talking about something abstract: the experience, recollection, or notion of chemistry class. It's not like a tiny waft of physical chemistry-class-particles are emanating from the poster. It's conjuring up an *idea* in your head. Sub-note: the word *whiff* and the word *eggs* are both strongly associated with *smells*, so that blocks and makes awkward the notion of *disorientation* used in your first sentence.  If I had written that sentence, I'd probably reconsider and rewrite it.

Comment: And *whiff* is generally an unpleasant smell, so it may be appropriate for *homophobia,* but I'd use "sign" or "evidence" or some such for the chemistry class.

Comment: @Dan Bron Oh, I see. Yes, I was thinking about the class as something physical: the professor, students, but I think you're right too.

Comment: "faint scent" used figuratively. "Can it be used?"  People will disagree over whether the writer's style is worthy of emulation.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I don't agree that *whiff* generally refers to an unpleasant smell. Can you please point to something that supports that assertion? It is true that for a pleasant odor one is more likely to breathe in longer than a quick whiff, and one is not likely to intentionally get more than a whiff of an unpleasant smell. But that's the only connection I see.

Comment: Virtually any word that refers to an odor specifically has an unpleasant semantic scent to it. Humans are visual hunters, not olfactory ones; mostly we only notice bad smells, and those are the ones we have names for. _A whiff of_ means a small, rapidly disappearing smell of something distinctive, and it can be used metaphorically for a short perception of something by other means. But it's usually not a pleasant something, at least for those experiencing it, viz _a whiff of grapeshot_.

Comment: In 1960s England, "stinks" was the schoolboy name for chemistry, so the use of "Whiff" in that context seems quite appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much doubt that "whiff" is neutral. It means a small and elusive quantity of a smell of something.

If you are asking if the smell can be **of** something concrete then

MW:

> Examples of whiff in a Sentence
>
> Noun
>
> I got a whiff of new paint when I entered the room.

And titles from Google books:

"A Whiff of Pine, a Hint of Skunk: A Forest of Poems" Deborah Ruddell · 2009

"Get a Whiff of This: Perfumes (Fragrances) - The Invisible Chemical Poisons" By Connie Pitts 2003

"A Whiff of Jasmine" Samantha Tamma · 2015

> Somewhere, sometime, when am busy meeting a deadline or a target, this backdrop appears to me like flashes of memories, a favourite background score or a Whiff of Jasmine.

New paint, pine, perfume and jasmine all appear to be pleasant enough and all seem to be real enough.

If you mean "whiff" in the sense of "a hint", "a trace", "a suspicion", etc, then that is figurative and in the following "of something", the "something can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have a cat who farts when excited. It is quite correct to say that she whiffs at those times.

Comment: You seem to be using _whiffs_ as a verb in your example. But the question is about using _whiff_  as a noun—specifically, whether a speaker or writer may refer to the whiff of an actual thing rather than figuratively to the whiff of an abstract idea.